# Direct sum isomorphism question

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, chinese-remainder-theorem, direct-sum

I found this problem and I'm not sure if I can apply the reminder theorem on it. Are $\mathbb{Z}_8\oplus\mathbb{Z}_{18}$ and $\mathbb{Z}_2\oplus\mathbb{Z}_{72}$ isomorphic? I tend to believe so, but I cannot prove it. Can someone help, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the Chinese Remainder Theorem, $C_2\times C_{72}\cong C_2\times C_9\times C_8\cong C_{18}\times C_8$, since $\gcd(9,8)=\gcd(9,2)=1.$

Comment: Thank you so very much! ^^